# Dialogflow Fullfilments responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have a case where I need to send an email when user types in something therefore I need to use the fulfillments using node.js and amazon for handling the email part but then I would like the response to be from dialogflow interface.

Currently I have something like this:

```
   let intentMap = new Map();
   intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);

   agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

   function welcome(agent) {
      var content = "Hello.\n\n"
                +""
                +"phone : " + agent.parameters.phoneNumber + ""
                +"\nIA";
      sendEmail("phone number", sendToEmail, content);
      agent.add(`Thank you`);
}
```

As you can see I want the response "Thank you" to be responded from Dialogflow Dashboard and i would remove the agent.add(`Thank you`).

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried removing the lines of code you do t want to run?

Comment: @RobertLevy I didnt get your point, you mean to remove agent.add('Thank you') , would the response from dialogflow get responded if I remove this line?

Comment: I tried to remove the last line of code but then it didnt responde at all chatbot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "Thank you" is written as your Dialogflow intent Text Response, and your webhook responds with either a non-200 HTTP response or an invalid response, Dialogflow will fallback to the "Thank you" from the Text Response field in the intent.

Even better, Dialogflow's [request](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) to your webhook includes a `fulfillmentText` property which contains the text Dialogflow will use from the Text Response in the intent from the Dialogflow console. You can use this string in the `agent.add` call to ensure your webhook succeeds, and you still control the response from the console.

Comment: agent.fulfillmentText shows undefined, how exactly I can get fulfillmentText?